# QMediaPlayer not available in PyQt4?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4, pyqt5, qmediaplayer

I was wondering if anyone has had any luck using QMediaPlayer in PyQt4?

```
>>> from PyQt4.QtMultimedia import QMediaPlayer
```

tells me:

```
ImportError: cannot import name QMediaPlayer
```

And it doesn't show up here either:

```
>>> dir(QtMultimedia)
['QAbstractVideoBuffer', 'QAbstractVideoSurface', 'QAudio', 'QAudioDeviceInfo', 'QAudioFormat', 'QAudioInput', 'QAudioOutput', 'QVideoFrame', 'QVideoSurfaceFormat', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__']
```

According to the [docs](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qtmobility/qmediaplayer.html?tab=3&q=QMediaPlayer) (and various code snippets I've come across), it should be there.
I'm using version 4.8.5 (Mac OS X 10.8.4).

(In my install of PyQt5, QMediaPlayer just works. However, I'm using pyinstaller to build the application and am not sure how well it handles PyQt5. In other words, I would prefer to continue using PyQt4 for this project if possible.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The QMediaPlayer class is only available in Qt5, so obviously PyQt4 cannot support it:

- [Qt4 QtMultimedia Module
  documentation](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtmultimedia.html).
- [Qt5 QtMultimedia Module
  documentation](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtmultimedia/qtmultimedia-index.html).

It is possible to [build PyQt4 against Qt5](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qt_v5.html). However, it will only include the subset of classes common to both Qt4 and Qt5. Any classes added in Qt5 won't be included.